# Adding a variable to .Attachments.Add

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am attempting to send an e-mail using a pathway variable in .Attachments.Add, but the e-mail is not including the attachments. When I just add the actual pathway after .Attachments.Add, without the variables (shown below), the e-mail includes the attachments.

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\id\Desktop\file_name.xlsx"
```

The method of attaching workbooks (using pathway variables) worked once, but now the workbooks are not attaching for some reason. Being that the string from the pathway variable and the actual pathway are the same, what would cause the workbooks to not attach when using a variable? Below is my code...

The two parameters (title1 and title2) are the workbook titles.

```
Sub Mail_Workbook_Comb1(ByVal title1 As String, ByVal title2 As String)

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim id As String
Dim path1 As String
Dim path2 As String
Dim rnge As Range
Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Dim distroRnge As Range

id = LCase(workbooks("Supplier_Automation.xlsm").Sheets("Home").Range("C3"))
path1 = "C:\Users\" & id & "\Desktop\" & title1 & ".xlsx"
path2 = "C:\Users\" & id & "\Desktop\" & title2 & ".xlsx"

MsgBox path1
MsgBox path2

Set distroRnge = workbooks("Supplier_Automation.xlsm").Sheets("Distros").Range("A29")
Set sht = workbooks("Supplier_Automation.xlsm").Sheets("Email Template")
Set rnge = sht.Range("B1:B19")
    rnge.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set wdoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = myname@email.com
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .body = ""
    .Attachments.Add path1
    .Attachments.Add path2
    wdoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    With wdoc
        .InlineShapes(1).Height = 345
     End With
    .display   'or use .Send
End With

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the second `.Attachments.Add path1` to `.Attachments.Add path2`?

Comment: Does "not work" stand for "throws an error"? If so, what's the error? If not, then what's happening? Remove `On Error Resume Next` to get critical information about what's really going on.

Comment: @Mistella That should have been path2. I edited my code to include that. I went and tested it again with path2, but the attachments still did not show up.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I edited my post to be more specific. What is happening is the path variables (path1 and path2) are not allowing the workbooks to attach to the e-mail. If I were to take out the variables completely and add the text the variables would be (.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\id\Desktop\file_name.xlsx"), the workbooks attach just fine.

Comment: Does the path that is being passed into the variable exist? You can use `DIR(path1)` to see the output if it exists. If so, it will return the path i think, if not it will return vbNullString

Comment: DIR() will return the filename if it exists, and vbNullString if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the title1 and title2 parameters were passing the workbook titles, I realized that they were not including the date that was being added to the workbook prior to the Mail_Workbook_Comb1 Sub being called. I ended up adding a date variable to the end of the path variable string and that allowed the path variable to match what was saved on my desktop

```
Dim edate As String
Dim today As String

today = Date

edate = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, today), "mmdd")

id = LCase(workbooks("Supplier_Automation.xlsm").Sheets("Home").Range("C3"))
path1 = "C:\Users\" & id & "\Desktop\" & title1 & " " & edate & ".xlsx"
path2 = "C:\Users\" & id & "\Desktop\" & title2 & " " & edate & ".xlsx"
path3 = "C:\Users\" & id & "\Desktop\" & title3 & " " & edate & ".xlsx"
```